# How to split string by specific keywords?

Tags: java, string

I have a String

```
String value ="Caused by:null pointer exception Caused by
                             : BeanCreationException.. WARNING: its just a warning..";
```

I would like to split String  after keywords "Caused by:" and "WARNING:" so that I have output like

- null pointer exception
- BeanCreationException..
- its just a warning..

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The SO way is to first try , post what you tried and what did not work and then ask for help.

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Caused by:` or `WARNING:` as your **delimiters**

**Code**:

```
String value ="Caused by:null pointer exception Caused by"
        + ": BeanCreationException.. WARNING: its just a warning..";
String[] sp = value.split("Caused by:|WARNING:");
Stream.of(sp).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

**Output**:

```
 null pointer exception 
 BeanCreationException.. 
 its just a warning..
```

**Note**: some part of code is in **Java 8**

Answer (score 1):

try using `split()` method

```
String str="Caused by:null pointer exception Caused by: BeanCreationException.. WARNING: its just a warning..";

String split[]=str.split("Caused by");
```

`split()` will return a array containing words before and after the split trem

Comment: OP wants to split by "Caused by" and "WARNING" substrings at once. Your solution splits the string by only "Caused by" substring.

Comment: @Aycan, OP can try out the rest..

Comment: Doesn't this answer contain essence of the solution. This gives a simple understandable point of beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You want to treat multiple substrings as separators. So my approach would be to transform all my separator substrings to a common separator, then split it by that separator.

```
String value ="Caused by:null pointer exception Caused by BeanCreationException.. WARNING: its just a warning..";

//Transforming substrings to a common separator
value = value.replace("Caused by:", "||");
value = value.replace("WARNING:", "||");

//Just splitting the string by separator
String valueArray = value.split("||");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `|`(*`OR`*) in [`#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
value.split("Caused by:|WARNING:")
```

*NOTE:It will give you first element empty in array if your `String` starts with `Caused by:` or `WARNING:` so be careful with that.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.split(REQUIRED_SEPARATOR)` or `new StringTokenizer(inputString, "REQUIRED_SEPARATOR")`

While using the StringTokenizer, you can iterate through the tokens by using `hasMoreElements()` and use `nextToken()` to access tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.indexOf("Caused by:")` to find all occurences of `Caused by:` then `String.indexOf("WARNING:")` to find all warnings.